# Time difference between the Datetime of an ebean and the Mysql data

Tags: mysql, playframework

I am storing the time of day in a Mysql database (e..g 7:15 am).
I don't know why, but since I upgrade to Play 2.6, I have a discrepancy of 4.5 hours.

When I look at the raw data in the Mysql database I get the correct time:

```
| id | start_time        | UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time) | TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',start_time) |
12 | 1970-01-01 08:30:00 |                      27000 |                                                  30600 |
```

But when I use it in my application I get a time 4.5 hours earlier:

```
Action time start: Thu Jan 01 04:00:00 GMT 1970 - 10800000 id: 12
```

The code:

```
    Logger.debug("TZ " + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone());
    for(ActionTime time : action.getTimes()) {

        Logger.debug("Action time start: " + time.getStartTime() +  " - " + time.getStartTime().getTime() + " id: " + time.getId());
    }
```

The MySql time is correct, and as it was earlier today before the upgrade. The timezone as printed in the logger is also correct (and it is UTC+1 now, so I am happy with the hour as found in MySql.

I did upgrade my Mysql driver as well, but reverting back to the old driver does not make a difference. As far as I can figure out the change in ebean version is the biggest change?

How can I figure out what happens?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trail and error, the solution was to add

```
[server]
default-time-zone=+00:00
```

to the server configuration. That solved the problem of the 4.5 hours offset.